# Strange NSDate after changing hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I want to change hour in NSDate. I did something like this:

```
NSDate *final = [gregorian dateBySettingUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour value:hour.intValue ofDate:self.dateForNewEvent options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
```

where self.dateForNewEvent = 2018-07-09 07:24:13 +0000
and hour.intValue = 5 and i expect date = 2018-07-09 05:00:00 + 0000 but i got 2018-07-10 03:00:00 UTC. How should I do it to get expected date ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing `NSDate` with `NSCalendar`: `NSDate` is a *point in time*, internally represented in UTC. To get the local date/time as it is *displayed on a calendar or watch* , you use `NSCalendar`.

So if you are in MEST (UTC+2) and set the time to "5" hours on your calendar, this will be UTC "3" hours.

To get the calendar date/time back, you could use `components(_:from:)` from `NSCalendar`.

---

Just check this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate * dateForNewEvent = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2018-07-09T07:24:13+00:00"];
NSLog(@"dateForNewEvent: %@", dateForNewEvent);


NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:dateForNewEvent];
[comps setHour:5];

NSDate *final = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
NSLog(@"final: %@", final);
```

Output as expected:

> 2018-07-09 11:11:43.542 jdoodle[22:22] dateForNewEvent: 2018-07-09 07:24:13 +0000
>
> 2018-07-09 11:11:43.542 jdoodle[22:22] final: 2018-07-09 05:24:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

To change the hours of a specific `NSDate`, you need to manipulate it via [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents). Please try below code for the same:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // YOUR DATE INSTANCE
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:now];
[components setHour:5];
NSDate *today5am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLog(@"Date ===>>> %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Hope this helps!